# what lead to the broadening of the scope of article 21 of the Indian constitution?

Tags: indian-constitutional-law

article 21 of the constitution

[no person shal be deprived of his life and personal liberty except according to procedure established by law]

the supreme court broadened its scope substantially by changing the meaning of "procedure established by law" to "due process" even though it's clear from the drafting body  that the terms "due process" were intentionally not included. what lead to the broadening of its scope ?

Comment: Why do you think the terms aren’t synonymous?

Comment: @DaleM  it was debated before drafting the constitution about If the term ‘due process’ was adopted instead, the judiciary would have the right to protect these liberties by investigating whether a law was consistent with the other fundamental rights. However, others argued that ‘due process’ allowed the unelected judges, who themselves are not immune from prejudice, to undermine the authority of the legislature by passing judgment of lawfully-enacted legislation. Ultimately, the members chose to retain the phrase ‘procedure established by law’. due process requires the procedure to be fair.